# VBA MS Access TextBox

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am pretty new to VBA , trying to develop an application using MS Access forms. I have been struggling to display formatted text in a Text box.. Here is what am stuck with..

I have two text boxes , where i would like to grab the text from the two boxes and display in a third text box in two lines.[third text box i would like to use to hold multiple lines , so i have set the Scrollbar value to 'Vertical'). Below is the code

```
MsgBox Me.Text0.Value & vbNewLine & Me.Text2.Value   // This works , displaying in two lines
Me.Text4.Value = Me.Text0.Value & vbNewLine & Me.Text2.Value  //THIS DOES NOT WORK , ANY ISSUE WITH MS ACCESS TEXTBOX PROPERTY SETTING?
```

Please help me on this. Not sure what am doing wrong.. My apologies if this has been answered earlier in another thread , i tried many different attempts in my code but clueless.

Comment: Might try setting the "Enter Key Behavior" to "new line in field"

Comment: Yes, I had that already but did not help... :-(

Comment: Hi , just figured it out.. I had the property set the "Rich text format" , I made that to "Plain Text" it worked.   :-)

Answer (score 1):

just figured it out.. I had the property set the "Rich text format" , I made that to "Plain Text" it worked. :-)